# GridPane cuts off Label when using COMPUTED_SIZE

Tags: javafx

I have a GridPane displaying descriptive Labels on the left side and content Labels on the right side. I set everything to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` in SceneBuilder and added padding to my elements so they don't stick together too closely. This works well if it wasn't for the fact, that the left-side Labels are cut off, if the content is big enough to take up the whole width of the scene:

[image: Recipe Info SceneBuilder]

Is there a way of making sure that my left-side labels are displayed in full, before the right side labels get their share of available width? Setting the minimum width of the first column to a concrete value works, but i would like JavaFX to determine the needed size for the first column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Text`s (can be found in Shapes) instead of `Label`s in the first column. In contrast to `Label`s `Text`s are not resizeable and `GridPane` cannot resize the first column to become smaller than the largest of the `Text` nodes in this column.

Comment: Thank you, now I will use `Text` instead of `Label` for static string